# Diferencia entre data frames

Tags: r

Tengo dos df:

```
x <- read.table(text = '
     Name     Month  Rate1     Rate2
     Aira       1      12        23
     Aira       2      18        73
     Aira       3      19        45
     Ben        1      53        19
     Ben        2      22        87
     Ben        3      19        45
     Cat        1      22        87
     Cat        2      67        43
     Cat        3      45        32
     Cat        3      45        32')

y <- read.table(text = '
     Name     Month  Rate1     Rate2
     Aira       1      12        23
     Aira       2      18        73
     Aira       3      19        45
     Ben        1      53        19
     Ben        2      22        87
     Ben        3      19        45
     Cat        1      22        87
     Cat        2      67        43
     Cat        3      45        32')
```

X es igual que Y pero con la última fila duplicada

```
Cat        3      45        32
```

Quiero que R me diga que esa fila de X es la que falta en Y.

He probado con  `setdiff(x,y)` pero como la fila extra tiene los mismos datos que la anterior no me da ningún resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero y por las dudas, si estás usando `setdiff()` del paquete base, esta función solo acepa vectores, si usas la del paquete `dplyr` que si trabaja con `data.frame` comparando fila a fila, ahora sí puedes observar las diferencias, que claramente en tu ejemplo no existen (al menos desde la teoría de conjuntos)

Lo que podrías hacer es:

1. Agrupar por todas las columnas
2. Enumerar las ocurrencias de cada grupo en una nueva columna
3. Aplicar el `setdiff()` para obtener las diferencias (ahora incorporando el numerador como parte de la comparación)

Por ejemplo:

```
library(dplyr)

x %>% 
  group_by_all() %>% 
  mutate(n=row_number()) -> x1

y %>% 
  group_by_all() %>% 
  mutate(n=row_number()) -> y1

dplyr::setdiff(x1, y1)

# A tibble: 1 x 5
# Groups:   Name, Month, Rate1, Rate2 [1]
  Name  Month Rate1 Rate2     n
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 Cat       3    45    32     2
```